# Wordpress Navigation Sub Menu Spacing

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, navigation

I have used the plugin Superfly Menu - to create a sidebar menu with a sub menu.  There is a space / gap in between the sub menu and main menu which I cannot remove.

Where in the CSS would I find the space or padding to allow me to remove it ?

I have tried resizing the menu, however this only changes the width of the menu "panel"and not the padding. There is also no option within Screenfly settings which causes this spacing.

```
.sfm-view.sfm-view-level-1.sfm-current-526 {
    margin-left: 0px!important;
    margin-right: 0px!important;
    padding: 0px!important;
}
```

I expected that to remove the space / gap between the main menu and sub menu panel, however it does not seem to be the correct selector

[Link to Site](http://demo.lookinside.co.za)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed width here is causing the trouble:

```css
#sfm-sidebar, .sfm-sidebar-bg, #sfm-sidebar .sfm-nav, #sfm-sidebar .sfm-logo, #sfm-sidebar .sfm-social, .sfm-style-toolbar .sfm-copy {
      width: 255px!important;
}
```

Comment: On some screen sizes when hovering over "investments" primary link - to expand the sub menu, the sub menu disappears before it can be clicked? is this a problem with the CSS also?